# What's wrong with my redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I create a React Native app. My `index.ios.js` where I add middlewares to the store.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import reducer from './src/reducers'
import * as sagas from './src/sagas'
import Scene from './src/components/scene'

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(createSagaMiddleware(...sagas), createLogger())
);

const CitiesApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Scene />
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CitiesApp', () => CitiesApp);
```

I have an action:

```
export const USER_FETCH_REQUESTED = 'USER_FETCH_REQUESTED';
export const fetchUser = () => ({
  type: USER_FETCH_REQUESTED
});
```

Which I call from `componentDidMount` in a component

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchUser());
  console.log('componentDidMount')
}
```

Also I have a saga:

```
export function* watchUserFetch() {
  console.log('watchUserFetch');
  yield take(actions.USER_FETCH_REQUESTED);
  yield fork(fetchUser);
}

function* fetchUser() {
  try {
    const user = yield call(() => Api.fetchUser());
    yield put({type: actions.USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED, user});
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: actions.USER_FETCH_FAILED, message: e.message});
  }
}
```

But the saga doesn't work. I don't saw `watchUserFetch` in console and `fetchUser` function doesn't run.

Where is my mistake? Why `fetchUser` doesn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create root saga

   ```
   export default function* rootSaga() {
       yield [
           watchUserFetch()
       ]
   }
   ```
2. then run rootSaga

   ```
   import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
   import rootSaga  from './sagas.js';

   const sagaMiddle= createSagaMiddleware();

   const store = createStore(reducer,
       applyMiddleware(sagaMiddle,createLogger())
   );

   sagaMiddle.run(rootSaga);
   ```

[webpackbin example](http://www.webpackbin.com/41xD1kfOZ)